# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest in Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I have the following function which works perfectly fine. Though when I click it, I get a warning message in the console that

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help
>   http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

I thought that this should by asynchronous as it clearly states so and other, similar functions that I use don't bring up this warning.

```
            $("#ChrdA").click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                 dataType: "html",
                 data: {},
                 async: true,
                 contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
                 url: "get_PlayerC.asp?W="+vWorld+"&C="+vAirC,
                 success: function(data) {
                   if (data.status = 'success') {
                     $("#ChordA").html( data );
                     $('#ChordA').show("slow");
                   } else {
                     alert(data);
                   }
                 },
                 error: function() {
                   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                 }
             });
        });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, after some fiddling and testing it seems that the warning message comes from the $().html(data); line. The .html() is apparently syncronous. But how to adjust the code to get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway **async : false** is deprecated in jquery ajax, and by default **async : true** setting is implicitly implemented by jquery ajax.

So as to get rid of warning, delete **async : true** line from your code.

for more go to jquery [docs.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Even with the `async: true` removed, I still get the warning message in the console. The warning comes from the `$('#ChordA').html(data);` How do I make that async?